# How can I move around the image with a tool selected in Lightroom?

Tags: post-processing, lightroom-4, retouching

When you zoom in on a Lightroom image e.g. to retouch someone's face, Is there a way to move to another part of the image while you have one of the tools selected (brush for example)?

The way I have been getting around this is by hitting return twice (to exit the tool), moving to another part of the image with the mouse and then clicking the tool again but it feels like there should be a quicker method?

Answer (score 5):

Try holding down the spacebar while the tool is selected

Answer (score 1):

You can use the navigator-windows (left upper corner). Clicking on the small picture change the selected part of your image -> [lightroomkillertips.com](http://lightroomkillertips.com/3-ways-to-zoom-in-on-your-photos-in-lightroom/)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this...

Comment: @connersz: Sorry for misleading you. I edit my answer and hopefully it is better to understand now.